# WiFi interference at event (Quiz App)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have to build a quiz app for one use at an event. I am not worried about my programming for optimal performance. I am however worried about the network. I will explain my problem below…

Details:

- Router: Asus RT-AC3200 (2.4Ghz, 5Ghz, 5Ghz-2) with NO internet connection, only LAN
- In-House Ubuntu server on local IP
- 75 Simultanious wifi connections in a room (20 meters in length, 20 meters in width)
- No other wifi routers in the area because the event is in a log cabin in the woods

The app is going to be very simple. Just a master application connected to the beamer, and four multiple choice buttons on the 75 clients. Do you think that the wifi will interfere / break? Assuming that the most devices will use one of the 5Ghz channels? Keep in mind that there will be no major traffic because we use only LAN with no internet connection. (So no video streaming or so…)

Comment: I’d be more worried about the clients if you’re letting people use their own phones. Also, your app doesn’t rely on multicast/broadcast, does it?

Comment: I couldn’t open the manual on the device I’m using, but I suspect that the router may only handle a fewer number of concurrent connections.   It looks like a home grade router, and there often limited at something more 50ish in number.

Comment: 75 clients is too much for some APs and no big deal for others. I have no idea if your device can handle 75 clients. But it can be done.

Comment: I am not worried about the router, but i am worried about that much wifi signals through the air. wifi signals interfere in the air right?

Comment: @Rubentje My biggest fear for you is if your app relies on multicast or broadcast, which are very painful to use on 802.11. If you can confirm that your app's traffic is all unicast and doesn't rely on multicast/broadcast, then I think you'll probably be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

802.11 standards use a form of "csma/ca" [carrier sense multiple access with collision avoidance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance).

**The simple answer is no**. 
In the woods with no other routers present the clients will not interfere with one another. They are synced by the beacon interval of the ssid they are associated with. Your router [has plenty of resources](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_RT-AC3200) to handle the clients you want. It also has a dual core processor, and three physical interfaces for wireless clients. (Three separate radio nics) 1x2.4GHZ & 2x5GHZ.

If your still worried about performance, configure the router to have two separate wireless ssid's. Let's call them testnet1 and testnet 2. In the configuration put `testnet1` on the first radio and `testnet2` on the second radio. You then tell half of your clients to connect to testnet1, and the remainder to connect to testnet2. Make sure both interfaces are bridged to your lan in the config  before you setup for your big event!

Edit: make sure `testnet1` & `testnet2` are not on conflicting channels. I think your second interface is in the 5ghz range, so you should be ok. I would double check.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I will post my findings after the event...